# how to use maven to generated jar file and run it?

Tags: java, spring, maven

maven version: pache-maven-3.2.5
java version(run): 1.7.0_75
jdk version: 1.6.0_65

I use maven package to generate jar file

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dmaven.home=/usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.2.5 -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/m2.conf -Didea.launcher.port=7535 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.2.5/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=14.0.3 package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building GAImage 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ GAImage ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/zhanglei/WorkSpace/IntelliJ/GAImageDemo/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ GAImage ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ GAImage ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/zhanglei/WorkSpace/IntelliJ/GAImageDemo/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ GAImage ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ GAImage ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ GAImage ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3:assembly (make-assembly) > package @ GAImage >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ GAImage ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/zhanglei/WorkSpace/IntelliJ/GAImageDemo/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ GAImage ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ GAImage ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/zhanglei/WorkSpace/IntelliJ/GAImageDemo/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ GAImage ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ GAImage ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ GAImage ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3:assembly (make-assembly) < package @ GAImage <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3:assembly (make-assembly) @ GAImage ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/zhanglei/WorkSpace/IntelliJ/GAImageDemo/target/GAImage-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.026 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-13T10:30:42+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

then I use java -jar GAImage-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar run it, it throws Exception

> Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace
>   [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]

I don't know why and I the program in fine in my java IDE(IntellIj 14)

```
iMac:target zhanglei$ java -jar java-archive-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
三月 13, 2015 10:20:47 上午 org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
信息: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@4bcfd41a: startup date [Fri Mar 13 10:20:47 CST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
三月 13, 2015 10:20:47 上午 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
信息: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-config.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]
Offending resource: class path resource [spring-config.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:316)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.service.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:51)
```

blow is my codes(5 files)

HibernateDao:

```
package com.dao;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class HibernateDao {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

MainApp:

```
package com.service;

import com.dao.HibernateDao;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

public class MainApp {

    HibernateDao dao;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 12 * * ?")   //每天中午十二点触发
    public void service() {
        System.out.println("service 正在执行");
    }

    public HibernateDao getDao() {
        return dao;
    }

    public void setDao(HibernateDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
        System.out.println("spring 初始化完成");
        MainApp mainApp = (MainApp)context.getBean("MainApp");
        mainApp.service();
        System.out.println("service 执行完毕");
        int a=0;
        a=a++;
        System.out.println(a);
    }

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@//centos7.local:1521/cent</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">zxqzuser</property>
        <property name="connection.password">123</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

spring-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd">

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="HibernateDao" class="com.dao.HibernateDao">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="MainApp" class="com.service.MainApp">
        <property name="dao" ref="HibernateDao"/>
    </bean>

    <task:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>GAImage</groupId>
    <artifactId>GAImage</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <cxf.version>3.0.3</cxf.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring持久化 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Without maven dependency Hibernate just silently ignores C3P0 configuration. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- cxf framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- oracle driver-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>codelds</id>
            <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.service.MainApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assembly</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](http://robert-reiz.com/2011/11/14/832/), it's likely caused by a dependency conflict, which can be resolved by using the maven shade plugin to ensure the meta-inf files are set correctly.

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
  <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
</transformer>
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
  <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
</transformer>
```

You can read more about the shade plugin here
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html

Also, you can run the jar using the maven exec plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Run as:

```
mvn exec:java
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks @Jimmy and @neilireson

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Main-Class>com.service.MainApp</Main-Class>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably a dependency clash. When the XXX-jar-with-dependencies.jar is created only a single file of any duplicates is included in the jar. This can sometimes cause a problem with version conflicts and configuration files. Intellij seems quite good at avoiding these problems.

The best fix is to use the maven shade plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin) to create the dependencies jar. Configuration of the plugin can be fairly complex but it does give you feedback about what it's doing. Below is an example configuration showing how to generate the same named dependency jar. You will need to work out which transformations on which files you need to get it working. You may also need to add exclusions to the dependencies, however shade also indicates when these may be necessary.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>jar-with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>

                <filters>
                    <!-- Prevent "Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes" -->
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>

                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>com.service.MainApp</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```